# Cannot get user profile using Facebook's PHP SDK in Laravel 4

Tags: php, facebook, laravel, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-sdk-4.0

I'm an app using Facebook's new PHP 4 SDK. I am trying to login using Facebook. I am using Laravel 4. But there seems to be something wrong and I can't figure it out.

Here is my code for the controller.

```
<?php
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;

class FacebookController extends BaseController{
    public function __construct(){
        session_start();
        FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('xxx','yyy');
    }
    //when the user clicks on the login button he comes to this function
    public function getLogin(){
        $helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper(url('facebook/user'));
        return Redirect::to($helper->getLoginUrl());
    }
    //when the user logs in, he comes to this function
    public function getUser(){
        try{
            $session = new FacebookSession(Session::get('_token'));
            $request = new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/me');
            $response = $request->execute();
            $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject()->asArray();
            dd($graphObject);
        } catch(Exception $e){
            dd($e);
        }

    }
}
```

This is error I am getting.

```
object(Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException)#160 (10) {
  ["statusCode":"Facebook\FacebookRequestException":private]=&gt;
  int(400)
  ["rawResponse":"Facebook\FacebookRequestException":private]=&gt;
  string(86) "{"error":{"message":"Invalid OAuth access token.","type":"OAuthException","code":190}}"
  ["responseData":"Facebook\FacebookRequestException":private]=&gt;
  array(1) {
    ["error"]=&gt;
    array(3) {
      ["message"]=&gt;
      string(27) "Invalid OAuth access token."
      ["type"]=&gt;
      string(14) "OAuthException"
      ["code"]=&gt;
      int(190)
    }
  }
  ["message":protected]=&gt;
  string(27) "Invalid OAuth access token."
  ["string":"Exception":private]=&gt;
  string(0) ""
  ["code":protected]=&gt;
  int(190)
  ["file":protected]=&gt;
  string(77) "/app/www/vendor/facebook/php-sdk-v4/src/Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php"
  ["line":protected]=&gt;
  int(104)
  ["trace":"Exception":private]=&gt;
  array(19) {
    [0]=&gt;
    array(6) {
      ["file"]=&gt;
      string(68) "/app/www/vendor/facebook/php-sdk-v4/src/Facebook/FacebookRequest.php"
      ["line"]=&gt;
      int(268)
      ["function"]=&gt;
      string(6) "create"
      ["class"]=&gt;
      string(33) "Facebook\FacebookRequestException"
      ["type"]=&gt;
      string(2) "::"
      ["args"]=&gt;
      array(3) {
        [0]=&gt;
        string(86) "{"error":{"message":"Invalid OAuth access token.","type":"OAuthException","code":190}}"
        [1]=&gt;
        object(stdClass)#159 (3) {
          ["message"]=&gt;
          string(27) "Invalid OAuth access token."
          ["type"]=&gt;
          string(14) "OAuthException"
          ["code"]=&gt;
          int(190)
        }
        [2]=&gt;
        int(400)
      }
    }
    [1]=&gt;
    array(6) {
      ["file"]=&gt;
      string(47) "/app/www/app/controllers/FacebookController.php"
      ["line"]=&gt;
      int(26)
      ["function"]=&gt;
      string(7) "execute"
      ["class"]=&gt;
      string(24) "Facebook\FacebookRequest"
      ["type"]=&gt;
      string(2) "-&gt;"
      ["args"]=&gt;
      array(0) {
      }
    }
    [2]=&gt;
    array(4) {
      ["function"]=&gt;
      string(7) "getUser"
      ["class"]=&gt;
      string(18) "FacebookController"
      ["type"]=&gt;
      string(2) "-&gt;"
      ["args"]=&gt;
      array(0) {
      }
    }
    [3]=&gt;
    array(4) {
      ["file"]=&gt;
      string(71) "/app/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php"
      ["line"]=&gt;
      int(231)
      ["function"]=&gt;
      string(20) "call_user_func_array"
      ["args"]=&gt;
      array(2) {
        [0]=&gt;
        &amp;array(2) {
          [0]=&gt;
          object(FacebookController)#128 (3) {
            ["beforeFilters":protected]=&gt;
            array(0) {
            }
            ["afterFilters":protected]=&gt;
            array(0) {
            }
            ["layout":protected]=&gt;
            NULL
          }
          [1]=&gt;
          string(7) "getUser"
        }
        [1]=&gt;
        &amp;array(0) {
        }
      }
    }
    [4]=&gt;
    array(6) {
      ["file"]=&gt;
      string(31) "/app/www/bootstrap/compiled.php"
      ["line"]=&gt;
      int(5784)
      ["function"]=&gt;
      string(10) "callAction"
      ["class"]=&gt;
      string(29) "Illuminate\Routing\Controller"
      ["type"]=&gt;
      string(2) "-&gt;"
      ["args"]=&gt;
      array(2) {
        [0]=&gt;
        &amp;string(7) "getUser"
        [1]=&gt;
        &amp;array(0) {
        }
      }
    }
    [5]=&gt;
    array(6) {
      ["file"]=&gt;
      string(31) "/app/www/bootstrap/compiled.php"
      ["line"]=&gt;
      int(5772)
      ["function"]=&gt;
      string(4) "call"
      ["class"]=&gt;
      string(39) "Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher"
      ["type"]=&gt;
      string(2) "-&gt;"
      ["args"]=&gt;
      array(3) {
        [0]=&gt;
        object(FacebookController)#128 (3) {
          ["beforeFilters":protected]=&gt;
          array(0) {
          }
          ["afterFilters":protected]=&gt;
          array(0) {
          }
          ["layout":protected]=&gt;
          NULL
        }
        [1]=&gt;
        object(Illuminate\Routing\Route)#143 (8) {
          ["uri":protected]=&gt;
          string(52) "facebook/user/{one?}/{two?}/{three?}/{four?}/{five?}"
          ["methods":protected]=&gt;
          array(2) {
            [0]=&gt;
            string(3) "GET"
            [1]=&gt;
            string(4) "HEAD"
          }
          ["action":protected]=&gt;
          array(3) {
            ["uses"]=&gt;
            object(Closure)#144 (2) {
              ["static"]=&gt;
              array(2) {
                ["d"]=&gt;
                object(Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher)#137 (2) {
                  ["filterer":protected]=&gt;
                  object(Illuminate\Routing\Router)#109 (14) {
                    ["events":protected]=&gt;
                    object(Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher)#14 (5) {
                      ["container":protected]=&gt;
                      object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application)#2 (16) {
                        ["booted":protected]=&gt;
                        bool(true)
                        ["bootingCallbacks":protected]=&gt;
                        array(0) {
                        }
                        ["bootedCallbacks":protected]=&gt;
                        array(2) {
                          [0]=&gt;
                          object(Closure)#74 (2) {
                            ["static"]=&gt;
                            array(2) {
                              ["app"]=&gt;
                              *RECURSION*
                              ["me"]=&gt;
                              object(Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider)#67 (2) {
                                ["app":protected]=&gt;
                                *RECURSION*
                                ["defer":protected]=&gt;
                                bool(false)
                              }
                            }
                            ["this"]=&gt;
                            object(Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider)#67 (2) {
                              ["app":protected]=&gt;
                              *RECURSION*
                              ["defer":protected]=&gt;
                              bool(false)
                            }
                          }
                          [1]=&gt;
                          object(Closure)#46 (1) {
                            ["static"]=&gt;
                            array(2) {
                              ["app"]=&gt;
                              *RECURSION*
                              ["env"]=&gt;
                              string(10) "production"
                            }
                          }
                        }
                        ["finishCallbacks":protected]=&gt;
                        array(0) {
                        }
                        ["shutdownCallbacks":protected]=&gt;
                        array(0) {
                        }
                        ["middlewares":protected]=&gt;
                        array(0) {
                        }
                        ["serviceProviders":protected]=&gt;
                        array(11) {
                          [0]=&gt;
                          object(Illuminate\Events\EventServiceProvider)#11 (2) {
                            ["app":protected]=&gt;
                            *RECURSION*
                            ["defer":protected]=&gt;
                            bool(false)
                          }
                          [1]=&gt;
                          object(Illuminate\Exception\ExceptionServiceProvider)#15 (2) {
                            ["app":protected]=&gt;
                            *RECURSION*
                            ["defer":protected]=&gt;
                            bool(false)
                          }
                          [2]=&gt;
                          object(Illuminate\Routing\RoutingServiceProvider)#26 (2) {
                            ["app":protected]=&gt;
                            *RECURSION*
                            ["defer":protected]=&gt;
                            bool(false)
                          }
                          [3]=&gt;
                          object(Illuminate\Cookie\CookieServiceProvider)#48 (2) {
                            ["app":protected]=&gt;
                            *RECURSION*
                            ["defer":protected]=&gt;
                            bool(false)
                          }
                          [4]=&gt;
                          object(Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider)#51 (2) {
                            ["app":protected]=&gt;
                            *RECURSION*
                            ["defer":protected]=&gt;
                            bool(false)
                          }
                          [5]=&gt;
                          object(Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider)#56 (2) {
                            ["app":protected]=&gt;
                            *RECURSION*
                            ["defer":protected]=&gt;
                            bool(false)
                          }
                          [6]=&gt;
                          object(Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemServiceProvider)#59 (2) {
                            ["app":protected]=&gt;
                            *RECURSION*
                            ["defer":protected]=&gt;
                            bool(false)
                          }
                          [7]=&gt;
                          object(Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider)#62 (2) {
                            ["app":protected]=&gt;
                            *RECURSION*
                            ["defer":protected]=&gt;
                            bool(false)
                          }
                          [8]=&gt;
                          object(Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider)#67 (2) {
                            ["app":protected]=&gt;
                            *RECURSION*
                            ["defer":protected]=&gt;
                            bool(false)
                          }
                          [9]=&gt;
                          object(Illuminate\Workbench\WorkbenchService…
```

Comment: Whats the error message you are getting? We can't debug for you without knowing what problem you are encountering.

Comment: I am hosting it in heroku. They are not showing any error. They just say that there is an error.

Comment: You haven't completed the login flow. Where exactly are you calling the `$session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();`, which completes the exchange of the `code` for a Facebook `access_token`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just going to guess its the same issue I had using the new Facebook PHP SDK.
the issue you're proablly having is the storeState and loadState methods in the FacebookRedirectLoginHelper use different PHP session methods than the Laravel Session.

Here is what I did to resolve that issue. You basically have to create your own class and extend FacebookRedirectLoginHelper

something like this.

```
<?php namespace Ninjaparade\Fbuser\Repo;

use Session;

class NPFacebookRedirectLoginHelper extends \Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper
{
  protected function storeState($state)
  {
    Session::put('state', $state);
  }

  protected function loadState()
  {
    return $this->state = Session::get('state');
  }
}
```

then you can do the following in your login method.

```
public function getLogin(){
    $helper = new NPFacebookRedirectLoginHelper(url('facebook/user'));
    return Redirect::to($helper->getLoginUrl());
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem isn't in the login method. The problem is  in the user method. After I lg in I am unable to show the authenticated user's profile.

Comment: That is because you haven't completed the auth transaction and your session status is not being set and loaded properly.

Comment: I am stille getting an error. Seems like you have used the new sdk with laravel. Are you sure there is no problem in the user function?

Comment: I am getting "Invalid OAuth access token."

Comment: Would be really helpful if you actually paste your stack error.

Comment: Just curious here, have you actually tried to update the session methods as I described because that's whats wrong here.

Comment: Thank you. I have solved the problem. The problem was that facebook doesn't send any data in the session. At least not anything useful. I had saved the $helper object in the session and in the redirect url worked with the same object. Very sorry for the inconvenience.